# Когда MySQL не использует индексы

Tags: mysql, индексы

Перечитывая [документацию по индексам](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/MySQL_indexes.html) наткнулся на абзац

> В некоторых случаях MySQL не использует индекс, даже если это возможно. Несколько примеров таких ситуаций приведено ниже:

- > Если использование индекса требует от MySQL прохода более чем по 30%
  >   строк в данной таблице (в таких случаях просмотр таблицы, по всей
  >   видимости, окажется намного быстрее, так как потребуется выполнить
  >   меньше операций поиска). Следует учитывать, что если подобный запрос
  >   использует LIMIT по отношению только к извлекаемой части строк, то
  >   MySQL будет применять индекс в любом случае, так как небольшое
  >   количество строк можно найти намного быстрее, чтобы вернуть результат.
- > Если диапазон изменения индекса может содержать величины NULL при
  >   использовании выражений ORDER BY ... DESC.

И если со 2ым пунктом все предельно ясно, то формулировка 1ого пункта никак не укладывается у меня в голове. Пытаясь разобраться я полез [в оригинальную документацию](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html) и не смог найти схожего описания вовсе.

Поэтому и хотелось бы узнать - в каких случаях текущая версия (5.7) не использует индексы, когда это возможно?

Comment: Перед тем как запустить выполнение запроса, строится план выполнения. В частности в этом плане (на основе собранной ранее статистики) просчитывается приблизительное количество строк, которое будет возвращено. И вот если по прогнозам планировщика этих строк будет более 30% от всей таблицы, то использовать индекс смысла нет.